# WPF: Visibility binding, event = null

Tags: wpf, events, binding, visibility

I have the following code:

```
    public event EventHandler LoadingControlVisibilityChanged;
    public Visibility LoadingControlVisibility
    {
        get { return _LoadingControlVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _LoadingControlVisibility = value;
            if (LoadingControlVisibilityChanged != null)
                LoadingControlVisibilityChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

<Label x:Name="loading" Visibility="{Binding Path=LoadingControlVisibility, Mode=OneWay}" Content="No Devices Detected!" FontFamily="{DynamicResource AppFont}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,0,0,0" FontSize="21.333" />
```

The first time the binding work, but after I change the LoadingControlVisibility nothing happens, after debug I notice that the event = null. Please help me solve this problem.

my text property works with no problems:

```
    public event EventHandler UUidChanged;
    public string UUid
    {
        get { return _uuid; }
        set
        {
            _uuid = value;
            if (UUidChanged != null) UUidChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=UUid, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="122.48,11.26,9,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="{DynamicResource MediumFontSize}" FontFamily="{DynamicResource AppFont}" Template="{DynamicResource TxtBoxTemplate}" Height="25" >
```

why is this different ?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're going for here. You're binding to a property called NoDevicesVisibility, but you're not manipulating that property anywhere.

Comment: Also, your property is called LoadingControlVisibility but your XAML binds to Visibility  ... Visibility="{Binding Path=NoDevicesVisibility, Mode=OneWay}"

Comment: Sorry copy past the wrong code. Fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Binding statement will not look for the event you have defined. You must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) instead.

Comment: The text Property works like this. Why is visibility different ?

Comment: @Mark - You would have to post more information about the "text property". I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @Mark - You don't show how you use that property in a Binding and you copied the wrong event :-) I see it now

Comment: @CodeNaked - Label.DataContext = SUS; // sus contain the uuid. sorry have to much events

Comment: @Mark - I tried a test with your code above and it did not update when I changed UUid. Are your Label and TextBox used in the same place? Try creating a very simple example and try to reproduce what you are seeing. The events you haven't won't be leveraged by the Binding, but there is not enough information to explain why the TextBox "works".

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite certain what you're trying to accomplish. My understanding is that you are trying to bind the visibility of your label to a Property named `LoadingControlVisibility` that is defined in another class. If that is the case, then your path is wrong in the binding. Your binding should be as follows: `Visibility="{Binding LoadingControlVisibility}"`

Comment: `{Binding Path=MyProperty}` is the same as `{Binding MyProperty}`

Comment: Yes. I know that. In his question he stated that this was his binding:  Visibility="{Binding Path=NoDevicesVisibility, Mode=OneWay}, which doesn't match the signature of the property he defined. He edited the question after I posted my answer. The second comment to his question confirms this.